# Get random element from MySql using Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I display an element randomly from my test table, so how can I get the id of this element:

```
$tests= DB::table('test')->inRandomOrder()->limit(1)->get();
```

because I want to compare it with an other id

Comment: `DB::table('test')->inRandomOrder()->first()->getKey()`

Answer (score 1):

`->get()` returns a `Collection` or records from your `test` table. You need to use a loop to compare a single record's value:

```
$id = 1; // Or whatever you're comparing to
$tests = DB::table('test')->inRandomOrder()->limit(1)->get();
foreach($tests AS $test){ 
  dd($test->id == $id); 
}
```

Or simply use `->first()` to return a single record from `test`:

```
$id = 1;
$test = DB::table('test')->inRandomOrder()->first();
dd($test->id == $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

`->get();` method return instance of  `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection.` For getting a single instance use `->first();`method. See also official docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset 
 For example.

```
$test = DB::table('test')->inRandomOrder()->first();
if ($test->id == $id) {
    // your logic
}
```